# pyodbc in Python to run an existing access query that asks for user input

Tags: python, pyodbc

I have an existing access query for example called *RunExampleQuery:

```
select name from table_x where date = [start];
```

But I can't seem to find the sql code that will run this query i.e

```
sql = """SELECT * FROM *RunExampleQuery WHERE [start] = ?"""

params = (datetime.date(2016,11,25))

cursor.execute(sql,params)
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of items are the issue:

1. `[start]` field must exist in *RunExampleQuery* in order to use it in `WHERE` clause
2. To bind parameters to prepared SQL statements, you must pass values in tuple or list. This requires converting scalar strings to these type:

**RunExampleQuery**

```
select name, [start] from table_x;
```

**Tuple** Parameterization

```
sql = """SELECT * FROM [RunExampleQuery] WHERE [start] = ?"""
params = datetime.date(2016,11,25)
cursor.execute(sql, (params,))
```

**List** Parameterization

```
sql = """SELECT * FROM [RunExampleQuery] WHERE [start] = ?"""
params = datetime.date(2016,11,25)
cursor.execute(sql, [params])
```

Comment: So [start] comes from a column in table_x called date. It's asking for user input in the MS Access Query to enter a date. So when I'm calling it in from the sql portion would it be sql = """SELECT * FROM [RunExampleQuery] WHERE date.[start] = ?"""

Comment: You cannot run a user prompt query like in MSAccess.exe. Have user enter through Python using [input()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) and pass that as query parameter.

Comment: Thanks Parfiat. I didn't want to do that because the query is used by different groups whom will not be using my python script.